# Enumerator initialization after declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, enumerator

Consider the following enumeration declaration :

```
enum Foo { Bar, Baz, Qux };
```

Now consider I want the enumerators (Bar, Baz and Qux) to have certain values. I can solve this by simply initializing them in the declaration :

```
enum Foo { Bar = 4, Baz = 2, Qux = 42 };
```

Now, what if I do not want these values to be known ? For exemple, when using other predefined values from other librairies, or when using the same value for two enumerators. Exemples :

```
enum Foo { Bar = MY_LIB_BAR, Baz = MY_LIB_BAZ, Qux = MY_LIB_QUX };
enum Foo { Bar = 0, Baz = 42, Qux = 0 };
```

I tried things like that :

```
// In header
enum Foo { Bar, Baz, Qux };
// In source
Foo { Bar = 0, Baz = 42, Qux = 0 };
// ...or...
Foo::Bar = 0, Foo::Baz = 42, Foo::Qux = 0;
```

Obviously, none of my attempts did work.

So, my question is as follows : is there a way to initialize enumerators outside of their declaration ? If so, how to do it, for exemple in a corresponding .cpp source file ?

**EDIT** : I can specify the underlying type of my enumeration. Considering that C++11 allows forward declaration, I thought that my problem could be solved since the enumeration becomes a complete type.

Comment: Are these real enums or you just want some constants?

Comment: Those have to be enums.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you can't do what you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The reason is simple, for example, enums are often used in `switch` statements. For these statements, the constants must be known at compile time. If you could omit them in the header, then the compiler would be unable to compile any `switch` in another ocmpilation unit since it would have no access to the values.

The same goes for all `constexpr`s: They must be defined where they are declared for exactly the same reason: The compiler must always know their values.

If you really need to hide away `int` constants, then simply define them as usual constants, e.g.:

Foo.hpp:

```
class Foo {
    static const int Bar;
    static const int Baz;
    static const int Qux;
}
```

Foo.cpp:

```
const int Foo::Bar = 47;
const int Foo::Baz = 11;
const int Foo::Qux = 4711;
```

Of course, you lose the ability to use these constants in a `switch` statement!

> I can specify the underlying type of my enumeration. Considering that
>   C++11 allows forward declaration, I thought that my problem could be
>   solved since the enumeration becomes a complete type.

This does not help at all! Forward declaration of enum constants is simply not possible, even in C++11 and C++14.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that enumerator names were sufficient for any use (`switch`, for instance). I believe I will have to leave my ugly values in the declaration. =/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way - enumerations always have initialisers as part of enum declaration and they cannot be splitted out to .cpp file. It is the same with C++11 typed enums.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations are constant values that are evaluated at compile time, therefore you can split it into declaration and definition like many other types. An enumeration declaration has to be its definition as well, so you need it to be complete with values and all when you declare it.

Comment: Since forward declaration is possible with C++11, I thought that my problem could also be solved, because I thought that the compiler only needs to know enumerator names when the code uses enumerators somewhere else.

Comment: @Nelxiost A forward declaration of an enumeration would look like `enum Foo;`, otherwise you define the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration type is a finite set by design intent.